# How does compiling this program fill up my computer?

Tags: c, gcc

```
int main[-1U] = {1};
```

It's very simple. Compile it with

```
gcc foo.c
```

No file will be generated (at least I can't find it with `lsof` when I hang GCC in the background `gcc & :`), yet 16 GiB of **secondary storage** (hard drive) will be eaten.

How does this work?

Comment: @Bob__ GCC defaults to `-O0`.

Comment: It just created an `a.out` file of 16 GiB on my hard drive. You cannot find the file with `lsof` because `of` stands for "open files". The file is not open any more after `gcc` completes.

Comment: @axiac I run `lsof` with gcc in the background.

Comment: It doesn't matter, @ibug.  The source is so short that `gcc` will compile it before you have a chance to see anything.  "In the background" is not the same thing as "suspended".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Shouldn't I be able to observe it while it's generating `a.out`?

Comment: You could use `ltrace` to see the system call that generates the file. Then you'll see why it is next to impossible to "observe" it's creation.

Comment: @MrPaulch I see `vfork` and `waitpid`, what's wrong?

Comment: @MrPaulch Do you mean something like `as` or `ld` is actually generating that file instead of `gcc`?

Comment: If you can catch it while it's actually running then yes, @iBug.  I had supposed that that would be difficult -- even with such a large static array -- but maybe not.  In that case, though, `lsof` might still be tricky to use for the purpose because you don't necessarily know either which process you're looking for or what file name.  The actual process writing the file is probably not `gcc` itself, and the file is not necessarily named `a.out` or any other predictable name while it is being written.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I caught `/bin/as` and `/tmp/abcdefgh o`. That's probably an answer.

Comment: Yes. The actual writing of the array is done by the assembler `/bin/as` into a temporary object file. After that the linker will do it's thing creating the `a.out`. But it's smart enough not to make a byte copy of the `.o` file. All in all `a.out` will be open for a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this mystery with a simple `printf`:

```
printf("%zu\n", (size_t)-1U);
```

This produces `4294967295` ([demo](https://ideone.com/Kc0I0g)) - enough to fill 16Gb of memory on systems where `sizeof(int)` is equal to `4`.

To see why this takes so much space in the file system, compile `foo` to an object file, and run `size` utility.

I modified the program to size the array to 1,000,000 elements. Here is the output that you get from running `size`:

```
$ gcc -c foo.c
$ size -A -d foo.o
foo.o  :
section        size   addr
__text            0      0
__data      4000000      0
Total       4000000
```

`__data` segment contains initialized data. Compiler fills it in because you supplied `{1}` initializer. If you omit it, the size of the executable on disk would shrink to a few kilobytes, because the array would be placed into uninitialized segment:

```
$ size -A -d foo.o
foo.o  :
section     size   addr
__text         0      0
Total          0
```

Comment: @iBug 16GB will be from virtual memory which is swapped in and out from secondary storage

Comment: @Pras Nope. Temporary file actually.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is wrong ([undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) since `main` should be a function (not an array). You should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108), and it could have been worse.

But I guess that `-1U` is actually 4294967295 on your machine.

You want GCC to fill a four billion element array, don't be surprised that GCC needs a lot of memory for that (it needs to reserve some representation of that monster at compile time).

The generated executable has four billion integers of four bytes. So it needs 16Gbytes. And yes, it takes a long time to compile that. Finally the linking phase fails:

```
ibug.c:1:5: warning: ‘main’ is usually a function [-Wmain]
 int main[-1U] = {1};
     ^~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o: In function `deregister_tm_clones':
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.tm_clone_table'
crtstuff.c:(.text+0xb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__TMC_END__' defined in .data section in ibug
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o: In function `register_tm_clones':
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x43): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.tm_clone_table'
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x4a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__TMC_END__' defined in .data section in ibug
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o: In function `__do_global_dtors_aux':
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x92): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
crtstuff.c:(.text+0xba): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That `ld` process needed 16 gigabytes of (virtual) memory as observed with `top`. I guess you experimented [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). The entire `gcc` command took 3:14 minutes on my desktop (most of which is that `ld` process started by it). Since `ld` failed the monster files it has created have been removed by the `gcc` driving program.

and I have 32 gigabytes of RAM on my machine (Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64, GCC7, compiling with `gcc -Wall ibug.c -o ibug`)

Comment: Note it's **secondary storage** (i.e. hard drive), not RAM.

Comment: It's a static *initialized* array of 4G ints. Assuming each int is 4 bytes, you are ending up with 16G binary. Of course the initialization of the `0` elements can be optimized out, but not sure the compiler will be smart enough to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Unsigned arithmetic is modulo one more than the maximum value of the given type.

Consequently `-1U` is `-1 + MAX_UINT + 1`, which will be `2^32-1` on an architecture where `unsigned == uint32_t`. If your `sizeof(int) == 4`,
`int x[-1U] = {1};` will need `4*(2^32-1) B =~ 16 GiB` of storage and the storage isn't being elided because it's not all-zeros.

The fact that your `x` is `main` plays no role (except that its being `main` will allow the linker to complete the linking, even though that will lead to a corrupt executable as your `main` isn't a function).

```
int x[-1U] = {1};
int main(){}
```

will require over 16GiB just as well, and this example should be perfectly defined (as long as your implementation can handle an array that big), unlike your example where `main` has a type it shouldn't have.

Comment: Does that program just create an array containing `2^32` elements of type `int` ?

Comment: That's about right, @Hollyol, but it would be clearer to say that the program *contains* an array of (actually 2^32 -1) `int`s.  The array has static duration, so it exists already when the program starts.  And the whole thing will appear as data in the program image because one of its elements is initialized to non-zero.

Comment: @Hollyol Assuming a common implementation (cuz the wrongly typed main should technically make the program undefined), it will simply cause a successfully loaded program to a have a global array of 2^32 ints (`int main[-1U];`). The program will segfault once the startup code tries to call this `main` as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized statically allocated arrays are usually go to the `.bss` section. They are implicitly initialized to zeroes. This data is not required to be stored inside the binary, because the startup code "knows" it should initialize this section to all zeroes when run. So we can say that uninitialized arrays, even when statically allocated are not consuming the binary size.

On the other hand the *initialized* data (non-zero initialized), as in your case is going to the `.data` section. Which *is a part of the resulting binary file*, because the initialization data has to be stored somewhere. In your case you  have `sizeof(int) * UINT_MAX` (`-1U = UINT_MAX`) of initialized data (presumably equating to 16Gb), which all add to the resulting binary.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you have virtual memory enabled on your system. So when you are trying to allocated 16 GB of data in memory, a file of that much size appears on the hard disk because of virtual memory.

16 GB because you are allocating 4294967295 number of ints of size 4 each.